# Primary vs. secondary coverage for someone without health insurance?

Tags: health, international-travel, insurance

What is the difference between primary and secondary coverage on a travel policy for someone who does not have primary health care? Is there any difference whatsoever (in terms of claims and/or payment to the health facility, or anything else)?

Comment: what's your country of citizenship, and where are you travelling? This makes a difference - for example, Kiwis in Australia will be covered for emergency care just because of their citizenship.

Comment: @MarkMayo I am from the United States of America - I'm a U.S. citizen travelling to Uruguay.